# Whichever whatever

Tags: questions

> - Whatever book you read will tell you the same.
> - Whichever book you read will tell you the same.

What are the meanings of these sentences and how are they used and where are they used? Please explain to me deeply.

Answer (score 5):

The criteria used to decide between '**whichever**' and '**whatever**' are the same criteria used when deciding whether to use '**which**' or '**what**'. 'Which' is used when choosing from a finite list of options that's known to both parties in the conversation, whereas 'what' is used when the options available are unrestricted, or unknown. The same rule can be applied to 'whichever' and 'whatever'.

To use the examples that you have given:

> Whichever book you read will tell you the same.

...means that from a known list of books (for example, five books on the topic, or the books in that person's possession) they will all yield the same answer.

> Whatever book you read will tell you the same.

... means the person isn't referring to a restricted to a set of books. No matter what book one reads on the topic, they will all yield the same answer.

Comment: Whichever means choose any one book from 5 of books or sets. Whatever means choos all book

Comment: @Merajhussain No. Whichever means you choose a book from a known set of books while whatever means any book.

Comment: Still I didn't get